# How do I enable zRAM with the highest priority in Android persistently?

Tags: ram, swap

I want to know how to use the `/dev/block/zram0` in full power, but I can't apply the command `swapon -p 32767 /dev/block/zram0` as it returns this:

> swapon: Couldn't swapon '/dev/block/zram0': Device or resource busy

So how do I modify the actual zram's line I have in `fstab.qcom`to change priority?

> /dev/block/zram0                                        none
> swap    defaults
> zramsize=3221223823,max_comp_streams=8,zram_backingdev_size=512M

Comment: It seems that you have a wrong perception about "full power" and high priority. `swappiness` is a different thing. // Resource busy means it's already mounted. // To set SWAP priority in Android's `fstab`, you can pass `swapprio` mount option: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/fs_mgr/fs_mgr_fstab.cpp#214. But I don't see any point in it.

Comment: In application, how to write it in `fstab`?